# reading a remote text file into a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a remote text file on http://somewhere... that i need to read into a string variable in vb.net. what is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `System.Net.WebClient` class. In particular, the `DownloadString` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(VS.80).aspx

Comment: It's very simple:
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string fooString = wc.DownloadString("http://www.myserver.com/foo.txt");